# How do I loop through a snapshot in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase structure is as follows:

[image]

The following code searches for the text selected by the user in a selectbox (2019/9/7 AMS MK7777) and returns the `ulds` object

```
FBLoad: function(){
            console.log($(".text").text())              

            var ref = firebase.database().ref("flights");
            ref
            .orderByChild("queryDes")
            .equalTo($(".text").text())
            .once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
                console.log(snapshot.val().ulds);
            });
}
```

What I'd like to accomplish is that the data of an object is updated by the data from the `ulds` object
The object that needs to be updated is the following:

```
var positions =  {
    "A": {h_arm:14645, "occupied":0, "ULD":"", "DEST":"", "CNTR":"", "WGHT":0, "TYPE":"", "SHC":[], "RMRK":""},
    "BR": {h_arm:16905,  "occupied":0, "ULD":"", "DEST":"", "CNTR":"", "WGHT":0, "TYPE":"", "SHC":[], "RMRK":""},
    "C": {h_arm:19165, "occupied":0, "ULD":"", "DEST":"", "CNTR":"", "WGHT":0, "TYPE":"", "SHC":[], "RMRK":""},
    "R": {h_arm:19165, "occupied":0, "ULD":"", "DEST":"", "CNTR":"", "WGHT":0, "TYPE":"", "SHC":[], "RMRK":""}
}
```

The final result should be like this:

```
var positions =  {
    "A": {h_arm:14645, "occupied":0, "ULD":"", "DEST":"", "CNTR":"", "WGHT":0, "TYPE":"", "SHC":[], "RMRK":""},
    "BR": {h_arm:16905,  "occupied":0, "ULD":"PMC12345QR", "DEST":"DOH", "CNTR":"Q5", "WGHT":2500, "TYPE":"C", "SHC":["RFL","RCM"], "RMRK":"OHG75CMF"},
    "C": {h_arm:19165, "occupied":0, "ULD":"", "DEST":"", "CNTR":"", "WGHT":0, "TYPE":"", "SHC":[], "RMRK":""},
    "R": {h_arm:19165, "occupied":0, "ULD":"PMC77785QR", "DEST":"DOH", "CNTR":"Q5", "WGHT":3540, "TYPE":"C", "SHC":["PIL"], "RMRK":"IND75CMA"}
}
```

I can't find a way to loop through the `ulds`-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To loop through the `ulds` try the following:

```
once("value", function(snapshot) {
 snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
   childSnapshot.forEach(function(uldSnapshot){
     uldSnapshot.forEach(function(nestedUldSnapshot){ 
       console.log(nestedUldSnapshot.val());

        });
      });
```

First, use the event `value` to retrieve the data, then use `forEach()` to retrieve the data under the random ids. Then use another `forEach()` to access the data inside the `ulds` object.

Comment: This returns all the children but I need to go one step deeper. (Now it still returns ulds as an object)

Comment: okay try this `once("value", function(snapshot) {
 snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
 childSnapshot.forEach(function(uldSnapshot){
    uldSnapshot.forEach(function(nesteduldSnapshot){
     console.log(nesteduldSnapshot.val());

        });`